# How can I delete a column in a VSTS DacpacTask?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build step in VSTS that produces a `.dacpac` file, which I pass to the Release definition, which then updates the database using the Execute Azure SQL: DacpacTask. When I try to delete a column, this is the output of the DacpacTask:

```
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3300540Z ##[section]Starting: Execute Azure SQL : DacpacTask
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z Task         : Azure SQL Database Deployment
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z Description  : Deploy Azure SQL DB using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z Version      : 1.1.2
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme)
2016-10-26T18:12:01.3674946Z ==============================================================================
2016-10-26T18:12:04.8304591Z packageFile= C:\a\r1\a\MyProject\Database\Database.dacpac
2016-10-26T18:12:07.4389560Z Publishing to database 'MyDB' on server 'mydatabase.database.windows.net'.
2016-10-26T18:12:08.3318189Z Initializing deployment (Start)
2016-10-26T18:12:25.4560124Z *** The column [dbo].[Foo].[Bar] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
2016-10-26T18:12:26.2098293Z Initializing deployment (Complete)
2016-10-26T18:12:26.2098293Z Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
2016-10-26T18:12:26.2098293Z Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
2016-10-26T18:12:26.2098293Z Updating database (Start)
2016-10-26T18:12:29.5605253Z An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
2016-10-26T18:12:29.5675257Z Updating database (Failed)
2016-10-26T18:12:30.4919483Z 
2016-10-26T18:12:30.6439495Z ##[error]

SerializedRemoteException      : 
SerializedRemoteInvocationInfo : 
ErrorRecord                    : *** Could not deploy package.
StackTrace                     :    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame 
                                 frame)
                                    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(Int
                                 erpretedFrame frame)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement    : True
Message                        : *** Could not deploy package.
Data                           : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException                 : 
TargetSite                     : Void CheckActionPreference(System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext, 
                                 System.Exception)
HelpLink                       : 
Source                         : System.Management.Automation
HResult                        : -2146233087

2016-10-26T18:12:30.6629481Z ##[section]Finishing: Execute Azure SQL : DacpacTask
```

I had a couple other database changes included in that build, but when I reverted the commit that deletes the column, the release succeeded.

I've also verified that the same issue occurs even if there are only `NULL`s in the `Bar` column.

(Obviously I could use SSMS to manually delete the column, but the point of having a CI/CD system is to automate everything so I don't have to do that.)

How can I delete a column using the VSTS DacpacTask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify BlockOnPossibleDataLoss argument to false in additional SqlPackage.exe argument of Execute Azure SQL: DacpacTask build step.
[image]